# .Net Framework, WebApi and SignalR

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, signalr

I have created a ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework) in VS2017, I have selected an Empty project and ticked the Web API checkbox. I don't want MVC. I install from Nuget Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR. All is well. Then I

1. Add an OWIN Startup class and add the line app.MapSignalR(); in the Configuration method.

   ```
   using Microsoft.Owin;
   using Owin;

   [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication4.Startup))]

   namespace WebApplication4
   {
       public class Startup
       {
           public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
           {
               app.MapSignalR();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. I create a Hub called MyTestHub with a single method Activate.

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

   namespace WebApplication4
   {
       public class MyTestHub : Hub
       {
           public string Activate()
           {
               return "Monitor Activated";
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. I create an html page to test with the following:

   ```
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>
   <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {

           var notificationHub = $.connection.myTestHub;

           $.connection.hub.start(function () {

               notificationHub.activate(function (response) {

                   console.log("response", response);
               });
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

The hub is created, $.connection.hub.start is fine, but notificationHub.activate returns "Object doesn't support property or method 'activate'". I cannot find the function on notificationHub but I do find it on notificationHub.server. However, calling notificationHub.server.activate does nothing.

I have tried the latest stable version of SingnalR and 2.2.2 (as the sample project) but nothing works. signalr/hibs is OK.

Any ideas? All the examples I have seen basically do this, but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```js
                notificationHub.server.activate().done(function (response) {

                    console.log("response", response);
                });
```